# use case for MongoDB to migrate from MySQL

Tags: php, mongodb, social-networking, nosql

I'm using **PHP** and **MySQL** for **social network system**

I have MySQL table named member_feed , in this table I save feeds for each member, my table structure is :

```
|member_feed_id | member_id | content_id | activity_id | active
```

in this table I have **more than 120 million record**, and every member has set of record.

I do this queries on this table :

```
1 - select * from member_feed where memebr_id= $memberId

2- update memebr_feed set active = 1 where member_id = $member_id

3- insert into member_feed (member_id, content_id,activity_id,active values(2,3,59,1) )
```

for each member daily I have at least new 50 feed by **beanstalkd** system and I have more than **60000 member**.

I currently work to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB and I'm new on MongoDB. so I need to convert this table to collection in MongoDB.

is this use cases good for mongodb and good solution  for my system to increase system performance?

Comment: What's wrong with your current system performance? Why would you think changing to MongoDB would make things better? You need to do your own benchmarks on your hardware and write queries to test. The sample queries you showed are simple -- but is that all there is? As written, your question doesn't provide enough detail to have a reasonable answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late replay,  I Margaret to MongoDB because when I execute select query with some conditions or update query for some record then the execution time is big and all recommendation for huge tables Said I need to no SQL database technique and the table grow every day with Thousands of new records, do you think this use case is not appropriate for MongoDB, please I need a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In mongodb joins between two collection is not available so, my question is where you will store member,content, activity?  i believe these should embedded in the member_feed.

Example:
member_feed Structure:

```
{_id:1,member:{_id:2,name:"Anuj"},activity:{details:"xyz"},active:false}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Anuj. in my case the member_feed collection only contain Ids (foreign keys) so I don't need to save member name or activity details in member feed table just fetch the feed ids from member_feed when I need to view feeds for member, so I don't need to use  joins.

Comment: @jetawe Well, then you can use the simple structure it should work fine for you...:{_id:1,member_id:12,activity_id:23,content_id:42,active:false}